# Is it possible to detect collisions when collecting into a HashMap?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I want to detect and warn about collisions in the logs when collecting a `IntoIterator` into a `HashMap`. The current Rust behavior of collecting into a `HashMap` is to silently overwrite the earlier values with the latest one.

```
fn main() {
    let a = vec![(0, 1), (0, 2)];
    let b: std::collections::HashMap<_, _> = a.into_iter().collect();
    println!("{}", b[&0]);
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

[(Playground)](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0e7cd5949e8f63e634ab6a9af3a092f8)

A possible workaround is collecting into a `Vec` then manually writing the conversion code, but that will introduce extra allocation overhead and unreadable code. Not consuming the original collection and comparing the `len()`s is less noisy, but still hogs 1x more memory (?) and can't detect where exactly the collision is happening.

Is there a more elegent way of handling `HashMap` collisions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do in the case of a collision, you might be able to use `fold` (or `try_fold`) and the [entry API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.and_modify)  to implement your custom functionality:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let a = vec![(0, 1), (0, 3), (0, 2)];

    let b: std::collections::HashMap<_, _> = a.into_iter().fold(HashMap::new(), |mut map, (k,v)| {
        map.entry(k)
            .and_modify(|_| println!("Collision with {}, {}!", k, v))
            .or_insert(v);
        map
    });

    println!("{}", b[&0]);
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba07683df567c497190dfcc123f14498))

Comment: I'd recommend instead of `contains_key` + `.get().unwrap()` to just use `if let` with `.get()`: `if let Some(&other_value) = map.get(&k) { if v > other_value { map.insert(k, v); } } else { map.insert(k, v); }`.

Comment: The [`entry` API](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/hash_map/enum.Entry.html#method.and_modify) allows for an arguably cleaner approach. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ba07683df567c497190dfcc123f14498)